# How do I make a copy of a list without changing its contents?

Tags: python, list, deep-copy

However, when I change new, it changes self._marker as well. I want to be able to change new, without it changing self._marker. I cannot use deepcopy either, since I do this operation several thousand times, and incur a huge performance penalty for using deepcopy.

What do I do?

Comment: if you want a deep copy, you have to make a deep copy. And yes, deep copies can be expensive. What are you really trying to do? (i.e. I think this is an XY problem)

Comment: Note to make a copy two levels deep you could do `new = [l[:] for l in self._marker]`

Comment: @Claudiu Im trying to make a copy of my attribute _marker so i can use the copy and mutate it, but the next time I do it, i want self._marker to remain the same, and not change

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Maybe create a list of lists, with the original `_maker` in the first column, and all mutations in subsequent columns?

Comment: It sounds like you want some sort of copy-on-write semantics: do a "deferred" deep copy, where `new[yindex][xindex]` can be a reference to `self._marker[yindex][xindex]` until you actually try to change it.

Comment: @SrikanthSrinivas: Are the changes you make a much, much smaller size than the object itself (e.g. do you change 3/4 values in an object of say 10,000 values)? If so maybe you can just keep track of the changes and undo them when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but your proposed solution does not work because you do not make a copy of the inner lists. They stay the same.

You can do this:

```
new_list = [e[:] for e in self._marker]
```

This performa a deepcopy which is what you need in that case.

This answers the question you asked. If you have other requirements, you need to make them explicit in your question.

Comment: OP already rejected this answer in a comment to a (now-deleted) answer

Comment: This answers the question though.

Comment: Sure, but it does the same thing deepcopy would do, and so suffers from that same issue. Also it's already [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237712/how-do-i-make-a-copy-of-a-list-without-changing-its-contents/36238470?noredirect=1#comment60105870_36237712).